# Finding Lowest Start DateTime and Highest End DateTime in each group by only EntryDate and Emp_id in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, aggregate-functions

I want to find

- Lowest "StartDateTime"
- Highest "EndDateTime"

When I'm grouping the data by

- The date portion of "EntryDate"(*Ignoring the time portion*)
- "empl_id" in MS SQL Server

**My data looks like this**
[image: **My records in table like this type:**]

**What the results should look like**
[image: **I want result like this type:**]

Comment: I inlined the images, and broke down your query requirements into 'select columns' and 'group by fields', Also used better wording of the  grouping by the date portion of "EntryDate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this ?

```
SELECT Emp_Id, MIN (StartDateTime), MAX (EndDateTime)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY Emp_Id, CONVERT(DATE, EntryDate)
```